# Block or redirect specific URLs during workday in OpenWrt?

Tags: openwrt

Is there a method to block or redirect specific URLs in OpenWrt during workhours? Say, `*.facebook.com` is blocked from 9am to 5pm local.

Answer (score 0):

For content filtering you can use opendns in openwrt.
See this [link](https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=31208) for configuration options.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, as OpenDNS cannot filter URLs by time of day.